# How to compare entered password with password in sys.user$ in oracle using php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, passwords

I have a mission: create a web application allow user access Oracle database as DBA and create a new DBA user in that apps.

I'm so confuse that how to compare entered password with password column in sys.user$ table. I don't know what's encryption type here.

```
    public function login($data) {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('SYS.USER$');
        $this->db->where('NAME', $data['username']);
        $this->db->where('PASSWORD', $data['password']);
        // How to fix correct line above

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Instead of rolling your own login function you should use PHP's built-in `oci_connect`. [Find out more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php). Because you only want DBAs to connect you need to pay attention to `session_mode` (hint: `OCI_SYSDBA`) .

Comment: @APC, It seems to be openly documented: [What Are the Oracle Database Built-in Password Protections?](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authentication.htm#GUID-F589A896-D775-4828-89F8-6A2BBEA413FE): PBKDF2-based SHA512 hashing algorithm. And some (maybe less official) more information: https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Changes-in-Oracle-Database-12c-password-hashes/

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - by "hashing algorithm" I meant the whole process, not just the encrypting hash. Oracle don't publish all the steps. However that Trustwave article was very interesting: I didn't realize the encrypted passwords included the salt. Thanks for that

Comment: Having a web based application login in as a DBA is a bad idea for what should be obvious reasons.  You don't need to be a DBA to create a user, you just need the CREATE USER system privilege.  You should be looking into a non-DBA user with this specific privilege, but not full DBA privileges.

Comment: @unleashed This's a assignment in my university. I have to complete it idea.

Comment: There's no good reason to be building an application to query the USER$ system table, and even less good reason to be trying to compare passwords!

Comment: @JeffreyKemp  Your suggestion so useful with me. Thank you sir, I have solve my problem with oci_connect. I didn't realize that.